# angular 1.5 access data in http.get without scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, angular-promise

I am using Angular 1.5.

I can't access my data, from the http.get, out the http.get.
Let me explain:

I have my component:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
class myComponent {
    constructor(
        $http,
        $scope)
    {
        var self = this;
        self.test="this is a test";
        $http.get(MYAPI).then(function(response){
        self.MYDATA = response.data;
        console.log(self.MYDATA)
        });
        console.log(self.test)
        console.log(self.MYDATA)
    }

}
angular.module('myApp')
.component('myApp.test', {
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    controller: myComponent,
    controllerAs:'vm',
}); 
})();
```

The console.Log give me:

*this is a test*  -->    for the test

*undefined*  -->    out the http.get

*Object {id: 1…}*  -->    in the  http.get

So I can't access to my data out the http.get and this is what I want.

Comment: the request is asynchronous so the assignment hasn't happened yet. the order of the logs should allow you to see this... you'll notice the one in the callback is the last one to fire despite being the first in readable order

Comment: That's right, i haven't noticed, thank you. And Have you a clue about using the data into the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http.get` is an asynchronous call meaning the program execution doesn't wait for the data to be fetched from server .

Thus by the time `console.log(self.MYDATA)` located outside of `$http.get()` is executed , the data has not been fetched from server that is why you get a `undefined error`.

To solve this problem or to handle asynchronous calls , you could do something like this :

```
 var promise = $http.get(MYAPI);
```

then access data in the following manner with the help of callbacks :

```
  promise.then(
            function successCallBack(response)
                {
                   self.MYDATA = response.data;
                   console.log(self.MYDATA)
                }
            ).then(
                function errorCallBack(response)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                }           
            );
```

Here is a nice article on [callbacks](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/angularjs-deferred-promises-basic-understanding/) that could help you !

Comment: That is working, thank you. But i don't know why, I can't have it in a child component. I can have access to self.test in the child controller but not self.MYDATA. But maybe this question is not related. Do i have to send the promise in the child and then to do the promise.then(), that's working but not very nice. Or is it possible to send directly the Data from the self.MYDATA?

Comment: You can declare promise as `global` variable and then you can access `response` in the entire script with the help of callbacks OR instead of a child component you could create a service and then send the `response` as an argument to that service .This would work since service calls are synchronous

Comment: Thank you. That has helped me